# How Repair lost Connection to Remote Repo on VS TFS

Tags: git, visual-studio

Visual Studio Issue.

I am using VS 2013 and its Git capability ion Team Explorer
I have one branch (master - the origin ) and have been successfully synching up with my remote repository (Hosted in Visual Studio Online)  for over a year

Suddenly I am unable to connect to the remote repo in Team Explorer.  It keeps telling me I need to Clone to my local repo (which, after that happens, shows up as empty.  I can exit VS and go back in on my solution and everything is there.

Also, Team Explorer is telling me that my local repo has no branches (it used to have the branches shown below)

In the git command window, here is the output from get remote show origin

```
git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://rafino.visualstudio.com/_git/<my repo>
  Push  URL: https://rafino.visualstudio.com/_git/<my repo>
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    ExploringGit                tracked
    LayoutRedesign              tracked
    master                      tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
```

Git seems to have no problem with connecting to the remote repo; VS is stymied.  Seems like this may be another of the many bugs in the VS Team Explorer git wrapper.

I am not really comfortable with the git command line and have done all my work in the Team Explorer.

Is there anything I can do short of cloning the remote back into a fresh local repo?  Or would clone on top of the current remote repo work?    It is quite confusing; who knows what is going on under Team Explorer's skirts.

For all its faults, it is still more convenient and preferable to work with VS Team Explorer (at least when it works!) than the git command line.

Answer (score 0):

Duh!

The Team Explorer Home GUI has two sections: Project and Solutions
When I connected to my remote repo and failed to see anything in the Solution Explorer, all I had to do was:

- go to Visual Studio On line and to my project
- click on the "Open in Visual Studio" link
- go to the Team Explorer Home  and the "Solutions" section
- and click on my solution  my solution on the list of solution(s)

Everything showed up and all was copacetic.  Problem solved.

In retrospect, I am not even certain that the trip up to the project on Visual Studio Online was necessary.

I am sure there is a tutorial on Team Explorer that explains the GUI and its features  The [one from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/work-team-explorer?view=vsts)  was useless.